# EMUI 8.0 Google account contact, gmail, calendar, etc sync not working

Tags: contacts, sync, huawei, emui

Bought a new phone. The Huawei Mate 10 pro.

No I am not using a chinese variant. And I do not have access to HiApp.

Cloud backup was enabled at startup.

Google contacts sync is not working, calendar sync is not working, weirdly though says gmail is not working (exclamation mark beside the title) but the gmail app is pulling mails.

2FA is enabled for my primary account. I thought this might be a problem, so I connected a secondary account as well. Same issues there.

Principally the services which are not syncing are, Calendar, Contacts, Gmail, Play music, google+, Keep.

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you go to settings>accounts>Google>***@Gmail.com and select to sync all? Any errors?

Comment: @Abochur So I went to settings > users and accounts > google > bla@gmail.com > sync all produces the error "Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly"